# 410 Status Displays "The page you requested was removed"

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have the following code behind an ASP NET web page:

```
Server.ClearError();
Response.Status = "410 Gone";
Response.StatusCode = 410;
```

Works a treat on my localhost where the page does NOT redirect and the user sees the content as intended. However when I upload to our staging site I see text "The page you requested was removed." instead of my page. I've looked through IIS 7 and I can't find where it's redirecting this page!?!?

All I want is to display an expired news article to users of the site but crucially let Google know my real intention.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I say that you need to add the `Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;` as:

```
Server.ClearError();
Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
Response.Status = "410 Gone";
Response.StatusCode = 410;
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I still get "The page you requested was removed"