# "The page you requested was removed" with 410 and redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http, http-status-code-410

I have following requirement:

- the user comes to a job page in our customer's website, but the job is already taken, so the page does not exist anymore
- the user should NOT get a 404 but a [410(Gone)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/410) and then be redirected to a job-overview-page where he gets the information that this job is not available anymore and a list of available jobs
- but instead of a 302(temp. moved) or a 404(current behavior) google should get a 410(gone) status to indicate that this page is permanently unavailable
- so the old url should be removed from the index and the new not be treated as a replacement

So how i can redirect the user with a 410 status? If i try something like this:

```
string overviewUrl = _urlContentResolver.GetAbsoluteUrl(overviewPage.ContentLink);
HttpContext context = _httpContextResolver.GetCurrent();
context.Response.Clear();
context.Response.Redirect(overviewUrl, false);
context.Response.StatusCode = 410;
context.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
context.Response.End();
```

I get a static error page in chrome with nothing but:

```
The page you requested was removed
```

But the status-code is correct(410) and also the `Location` is set correctly, just no redirect.

If i use `Redirect` and set the status before:

```
context.Response.StatusCode = 410;
context.Response.Redirect(overviewUrl, true); // true => endReponse
```

the redirect happens but i get a 302 instead of the desired 410.

Is this possible at all, if yes, how?

Comment: Response should fulfil two conditions for browser to make a redirect: response code should be 3xx or 201, and Location header should be set. Maybe just return 410 without location and then do redirect client side? Via javascript or other means like described here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections#html_redirections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're trying to bend the rules of `http`. [The documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/410) states

> The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 410 Gone client error response code indicates that access to the target resource is no longer available at the origin server and that this condition is likely to be permanent.

> If you don't know whether this condition is temporary or permanent, a 404 status code should be used instead.

In your situation either `404` or `410` seems to be the right status code, but `410` does not have any statement about redirection as a correct behavior that browsers should implement, so you have to assume a redirect is not going to work.

Now, to the philosophically right way to implement your way out of this...

With your stated requirements, "taken" does not mean the resource is gone. It means it exists for the client that claimed it. So, do you `302 Redirect` a different client to something else that might be considered correct? You implemented that, and it seems like the right way to do it.

That said, I don't know if you "own" the behavior across the client and server to change the requirements to this approach. Looking at it from the "not found" angle, a `404` also seems reasonable. It's not found because "someone" already has the resource.

In short if your requirements are set in stone, they may be in opposition to the HTTP spec. If you still *must* have a `410` then you would need to change the behavior on the client-side somehow. If that's JavaScript, you'd need to expect a `410` from the server that returns a helpful payload that the client interprets to do something else (e.g. like a simulated redirect).

If you don't "own" the client code... well that's a different problem.

There's a [short blog post](https://www.clickminded.com/status-code-410/) by Tommy Griffth that backs up what I am saying. Take a read. It says in part,

> The “Gone” error response code means that the page is truly gone—it’s no longer available on the origin server and no redirect was set up.

> Sometimes, webmasters want to be very explicit to Google and other search engines that a page is gone. This is a much more direct signal to Google that a page is truly gone and never coming back. It's slightly more direct than a 404.

So, is it possible? Yes, but you're going to need to "fake" it by changing both client and server code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. ""taken" does not mean the resource is gone". The resource is a job and it's indeed _gone_ and this job-page will never come back(it's deleted), so technically a 410 is the corect status-code for google. The original url must be delisted. But we want that the job-seeker will not go away frustrated but look for a similar job, so he will be redirected to the overview of available jobs. It's not comparable to the first location but it will give the user a better experience and an explanation(on the overview he will get a message about the taken-job).

Comment: Yes, i own the server and client-code. But how i would implement it with javascript (or server code if possible) that the client gets a 410 for the taken job page but will be redirected to an overview, but so that google will not treat that location as a replacement for the old url?

Comment: I have tried to provide a custom router for the gone-jobs that uses `Server.TransferRequest` to transfer it to the overview. This works perfectly. There i can provide the info-label for the user. But i can't set `Reponse.StatusCode=410` in the controller, because then all the user will see is "The page you requested was removed." According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15117405/410-status-displays-the-page-you-requested-was-removed) it should work if you set `TrySkipIisCustomErrors` to `true`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Hm, I'd have to think on it, but it seems like you could return the `410` but add a payload or header that Google will ignore, but contains the URI to the overview page the client could go to. That places the burden on the client taking a custom action (the "fake it" part I mentioned in the answer). I know it's not ideal...

Comment: After you saying you can't set the code to 410 on the transfer, set a 200 instead. As you say the interaction for the user is to view an overview page, so a 200 makes sense for that, even though the intention of the user was to view that specific job.

Comment: I have solved it in a [different way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74987096/284240), but your answer was the correct one in general, so i've accepted it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I will accept [Kit's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74978399/284240) since he's right in general, but maybe i have overcomplicated my requirement a bit, so i want to share my solution:

What i wanted actually?

1. provide crawlers a 410 so that the taken job page is delisted from search engine indexes
2. provide the user a better exeprience than getting a 404, so redirect him to a job-overview where he can find similar jobs and gets a message

These are two separate requirements and two separate users, so i could simply provide a solution for a crawler and one for a "normal" user.

In case someone needs something similar i can provide more details, just a snippet:

```
if (HttpContext.Current.IsInSearchBotMode())
{
    Deliver410ForSearchBots(HttpContext.Current);
}
else
{
    // redirect(301) to job-overview, omitting details
}
```

---

```
private void Deliver410ForSearchBots(HttpContext context)
{
    context.Response.Clear();
    context.Response.StatusCode = 410;
    context.Response.StatusDescription = "410 job taken";
    context.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
    context.Response.End();
}
```

---

```
public static bool IsInSearchBotMode(this HttpContext context)
{
    ISearchBotConfiguration configuration = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ISearchBotConfiguration>();
    string userAgent = context.Request?.UserAgent;
    return !(string.IsNullOrEmpty(userAgent) || configuration.UserAgents == null)
        && configuration.UserAgents.Any(bot => userAgent!.IndexOf(bot, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0);
}
```

These user-agents i have used for the crawler detection:

```
<add key="SearchBot.UserAgents" value="Googlebot;Googlebot-Image;Googlebot-News;APIs-Google;AdsBot-Google;AdsBot-Google-Mobile;AdsBot-Google-Mobile-Apps;DuplexWeb-Google;Google-Site-Verification;Googlebot-Video;Google-Read-Aloud;googleweblight;Mediapartners-Google;Storebot-Google;LinkedInBot;bitlybot;SiteAuditBot;FacebookBot;YandexBot;DataForSeoBot;SiteCheck-sitecrawl;MJ12bot;PetalBot;Yeti;SemrushBot;Roboter;Bingbot;AltaVista;Yahoobot;YahooCrawler;Slurp;MSNbot;Lycos;AskJeaves;IBMResearchWebCrawler;BaiduSpider;facebookexternalhit;XING-contenttabreceiver;Twitterbot;TweetmemeBot" />
```

Comment: Nice. No bending of HTTP rules and no weirdness at either the client (looking for a special payload) or server (sending this weird payload in the first place) end.